# Is it possible to use an iMac's screen as a second monitor?

Tags: windows, imac, display, desktop

Is it possible to use an iMac (early 2008 model) *as* a second monitor (note: not *with* a second monitor)?

I have a Windows 7 laptop (for work) and when working at home it would be nice if I could somehow connect my iMac to act as a second monitor.

Of course, the Mini DisplayPort on my iMac can probably not be used since that is for connecting an extra monitor to the iMac, but maybe there is some neat cross-platform application to do dual-display over USB?

Also, any solution for the same thing between a MacBook and an iMac would be nice to know as well.

Comment: Could you clarify two things, which iMac (size and year), as well as if you are using the DisplayPort port for another display? Some iMacs (27" and depending on years) allowed you to use the iMac as an external monitor.

Comment: @jmlumpkin: done

Answer (score 3):

I don't know your iMac spec, but look at [Apple knowledge base](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3924)

> With Target Display mode, you can use your iMac (27-inch, Mid 2010) or
>   iMac (27-inch, Late 2009) with Mac OS X as an external display.
>   Connect any computer or other device with a Mini DisplayPort to your
>   27-inch iMac using a Mini DisplayPort to Mini DisplayPort cable or
>   using a converter that converts other electrical, video, and audio
>   protocols from another source device to Mini DisplayPort compliant
>   signals.  (Cables and converters available separately.)

Comment: The question has been edited to show that it’s about a 2008 iMac, so TDM won’t work.

Comment: For those that bump into this question, Target Display Mode is *not* supported anymore for iMac models after Late 2014, see https://support.apple.com/el-gr/HT204592 for details.

Answer (score 2):

[Air Display](http://avatron.com/apps/air-display) application, supports both Mac and Windows. And appears to be for free.

Seemed really promising, but after installation on an iMac with OSX 10.5.8 and a laptop with Windows 7, both computers failed to detect each other.
I restarted both app's, turning on/off, restarted the Bonjour service but couldn't get it to work :-(

Answer (score 1):

Easy way [ScreenRecycler](http://www.screenrecycler.com/ScreenRecycler.html), but commercial - and for Macs only.

For windows - you can try search for some freeware `vnc` solution.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mWjwRV8ulAM
This videos shows a user using his iMac as a display for his MacBook Pro, i.e it's possible.

Comment: Hmm, the solution used in the video (a specific cable: "Belkin Mini DisplayPort to Mini DisplayPort") seems to only apply for 27 inch iMacs and compatible macbooks. More info about the cable requriements: http://www.cultofmac.com/using-imac-as-monitor-requires-very-specific-cable/20176

Comment: get an adapter/dongle it should work

Answer (score -1):

This will not work unless your iMac is a 27" late 2009 or later, or an iMac 21.5" *after* late 2009.